# RequireJS: Conditionally Load Polyfill Using Modernizr

Tags: requirejs, modernizr, polyfills

How do you wrap a polyfill script as an AMD module and conditionally load it using Modernizr and RequireJS?

(Figured it out while I was drafting my question - posting answer for anyone else trying to do the same thing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polyfill I needed to load was [jquery-placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) for browsers that don't support input placeholders. It does not provide AMD support out of the box.

First I wrapped it as an AMD module like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
  (function(window, document, $) {
    ... polyfill ...
  }(this, document, jQuery));
});
```

Then in `main.js` I used Modernizr to conditionally `require()` the polyfill script:

```
require(['jquery', 'modernizr'], function ($, Modernizr) {
  if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
    require(['jquery', 'placeholder'], function ($) {
      $('#input').placeholder();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: in your example you're requiring jQuery twice. If jQuery placeholder is the only reason jQuery is needed, then in I would only require Modernizr and not jQuery in the the first step. Also using a [RequireJS shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) instead of copying the vendor source code inside a module wrapper is considered better practice as you leave the vendor code as is and can replace it at any moment.